# "Thanks to" + noun

Tags: syntactic-analysis, nonfinite-verbs

Can a phrase "Thanks to the wizardry of modern technology /.../" be considered as a non-finite verb form (infinitive, gerund or participle)?

What function does it have?

Thank you.

Comment: Like _according to_, you mean? Not really, though the original was something on the lines of _Thanks (go/are expressed) to_, which involves some verb, but no verb forms. The fact that _according to_ uses a participle form is irrelevant; preposed adverbial phrases can take any form.

Comment: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thanks%20to) class 'thanks to' as a compound preposition, alongside 'because of', 'due to'. Perhaps Crystal would include 'as a result of' by analogy.

Answer (score 1):

No, since "thanks to" introduces an adjunct whose meaning is similar to that of "because of" https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/thanks
There are no verbal traces in what follows it, apart from the main clause that would come after your dots, obviously.